# Is a minor sloppiness acceptable in The Washington Post?

Tags: sentence-construction

I don't know German, so I can't tell if the English translation of Angela Merkel's speech is accurate, but even so the quote doesn't integrate in the fluency of the previous content of the sentence in the following [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/following-trumps-trip-merkel-says-europe-cant-rely-on-us-anymore/2017/05/28/4c6b92cc-43c1-11e7-8de1-cec59a9bf4b1_story.html?utm_term=.1b0443494269):

> LONDON — German Chancellor Angela Merkel on Sunday declared a new chapter in U.S.-European relations after contentious meetings with President Trump last week, saying that Europe “really must take our fate into our own hands.”

Can Europe take our fate into our own hands?

If I were to correct it I'd write as:

> ... saying that **we** (Europe or the Europeans) “really must take our fate into our own hands.”

So, what would you say about that? Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Is your problem that it's in third person, using "Europe"?  There's nothing wrong with the original quote.

Comment: So that's ok in English? Shouldn't agree?

Comment: The way the punctuation is used "*Europe*" is implied by whatever Merkel said, but she did not exactly say "Europe" because it's not quoted, what she did say is "I can only say that *we Europeans* must really take our fate into our own hands". "*We Europeans*" got changed to "*Europe*".

Comment: *Wir Europäer müssen unser Schicksal in unsere eigene Hand nehmen*.  Literally/woodenly: We Europeans must our fate into our own hand take. In English (and in German) we don't need to say "fates" and "hands" because the expression is a figurative one.  Trump wants Europe to cough up some cash for NATO. Should we imagine millions of people coughing, @Lucian Sava? Or wonder how a continent can cough?

Comment: No, certainly not, so let it be...

Comment: Europe must take its fate in its own hands. OR, We in Europe must take our fate in our own hands. You can have EUROPE And OUR without we!! Lucian Savo is right. This mistake is all over the place in US publications. They just can't seem to GET IT RIGHT. :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's great! Put that in an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While striped yak is correct that the most correct thing grammar-wise would be to adjust the quote with brackets, "correctness" here really comes down not to grammar but to style.

As mentioned in [this Slate article](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2010/03/dewey_defeat_truman.html) (which I offer in lieu of a link to the AP Stylebook itself, which requires a paid subscription, or to the *Washington Post's* own style guide, if it's even publicly available):

> Most newspaper style guides are unambiguous about attempts to "clean up" the language of an interviewee. "Never alter quotations even to correct minor grammatical errors or word usage," says the style book of the Associated Press. The *New York Times* style guide is equally explicit: "The Times does not 'clean up' quotations." *Washington Post* policy says that "[w]hen we put a source's words inside quotation marks, those exact words should have been uttered in precisely that form."

The article goes on to say that some minor fixes, such as removing "um" or "uh," might be acceptable, but the general rule is to not adjust quotes unless really truly necessary, and even then, a newspaper is more likely to just paraphrase and put quotes around only a word or two, if doing a longer quote isn't easy without big adjustments.

In the case of the Merkel quote, as others have pointed out, the reader can easily surmise what she means, and European readers might even find the use of "Europe...our" to be grammatically correct, so no adjustment was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically correct if the author of the sentence is European or otherwise considers him- or herself to be part of that European "we". Given that the Washington Post is an American newspaper, however, that reading is probably not reality.

To make it really, technically, impeccably correct, I think it would be:

> ...saying that Europe "really must take [their] fate into [their] own hands."

Or, as Peter said in the comments, changing the translation to:

> ...saying that "we Europeans must really take our fate into our own hands."

However, the journalist may not have been a fluent enough German speaker, or "authorized" by their employer, to make such translations.

The purpose, in my opinion, of journalistic writing is to communicate the point as clearly and simply as possible. I think the writer has done just that with the sentence they chose. It's clear that Merkel is talking about Europe, but it hasn't been made confusing or distracting with [excessive] [bracketry].